# Multi criteria analysis or k-means clustering

Tags: analysis, research

I have more of a research question. If I have point locations (say gas stations) and information about the gas stations (area, type etc) and I want to determine which gas stations would potential be at risk of closing, should I use a multi criteria analysis or k-means?